# Session data not saving through controller

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, controllers, session

I've got a couple controller that I'm trying to use to save and retrieve a custom piece of session data.  It works on my local development environment but doesn't work on my staging environment.  Here's the specs for my local environment:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.0.16
- Magento 2.1.5
- Mysql 5.7

Here's the spec's for my staging environment

- Apache 2.2
- PHP 7.0.15
- Mysql 5.6
- Magento 2.1.5
- Redis
- Varnish

Here's my get controller:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\StoreLocator\Controller\Store;


class Get extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Save constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ){
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $selectedStore = $this->customerSession->getSelectedStore();

        return $this->resultFactory
            ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
            ->setData($selectedStore);
    }
}
```

Here's my set controller:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\StoreLocator\Controller\Store;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * Save constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ){
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        $this->session->setSelectedStore($data);

        return;
    }
}
```

I'm calling the controllers via AJAX call on product details pages.  On my staging environment, the getter always returns null.  I thought maybe it was an issue with full page cache being enabled on my staging environment because I don't use any caching on my local environment, but I disabled full page cache on staging and the issue persists.

Any ideas what's going on and/or how to fix this issue?  I've reworked things to use a cookie but I'd really like to use the customer session.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to use registry as your controller name is not changing, you can add the following code in your 'set' controller action class file:

> use Magento\Framework\Registry;
>
> protected $registry;

And inject this in your class construct method.

```
public function __construct(Registry $registry)
{
  $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

You should then be able to register your data like below:

> $this->registry->register('your_data', $data);

And in your 'get' controller action class file:

> use Magento\Framework\Registry;
>
> protected $registry;

And inject this in your class construct method.

```
public function __construct(Registry $registry)
{
  $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

And to retrieve data from registry do:

> $this->registry->getData('your_data');

Comment: FYI Magento\Framework\Registry has been deprecated since 100.0.2